# Is there a way to stay login within docusign word add-in?

Tags: ms-word, docusignapi, add-in

Every time I close out of word and re open I need to login to Docusign for Word in order to use the request for signatures feature. Is there a way I can stay logged in without having to re login every time I?

Contacted DocuSign Support and I was told to post my question here.

Comment: what version of Word and the add-in are you using? are you using the rich client? Word Online? Windows? Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocuSign Word Add-in ) (https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104218065?tab=Overviewlatest version works like this:

It uses OAuth Auth Code Grant so that end-users have to login with thier DocuSign credentials. When the add-in obtains an access token (good for 8 hours) it also obtains a refresh token and both are stored in a cookie. The add-in would use the refresh token to obtain a new access token so that there's no need to login again.

So, what you see probably means there's an issue storing or retrieving cookies. This can be for several reasons and it depends on the version you use (web vs. rich client) as well as the platform (Windows vs. Mac).

In Windows, the IE security settings can prevent "third party cookies" which would cause this issue (as the add-in stores the cookie on a different domain than Word). Resetting IE settings to default typically fixes this issue, but if IT controls these settings - you may need to work with your IT department to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you, looks like after adding the add-in with office365 instead of the store within word the issue was resolved.

Comment: glad it was resolved Lucy. Do you mind marking this question as answered? thanks!